# Average column if value in other column matches and print as additional column

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like this:

```
Score      1      24      HG      1  
Score      2      26      HG      2  
Score      5      56      RP      0.5  
Score      7      82      RP      1  
Score      12     97      GM      5  
Score      32     104     LS      3
```

I would like to average column 5 if column 4 are identical and print the average as column 6 so that it looks like this:

```
Score      1      24      HG      1      1.5
Score      2      26      HG      2      1.5  
Score      5      56      RP      0.5    0.75  
Score      7      82      RP      1      0.75  
Score      12     97      GM      5      5  
Score      32     104     LS      3      3
```

I have tried a couple of solutions I found on here.
e.g.

```
awk '{ total[$4] += $5; ++n[$4] } END { for(i in total) print i, total[i] / n[i] }'
```

but they all end up with this:

```
HG      1.5
RP      0.75  
GM      5  
LS      3
```

Which is undesirable as I lose a lot of information.

Comment: Are the same values in the column 4 always adjacent?

Comment: They are always yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through your table twice: calculate the averages (as you already) do on the first iteration, and then print them out on the second iteration:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { total[$4] += $5; ++n[$4] } NR>FNR { print $0, total[$4] / n[$4] }' file file
```

Notice the `file` twice at the end. While going through the "first" file, `NR==FNR`, and we sum the appropriate values, keeping them in memory (variables `total` and `n`). During "second" file traversal, `NR>FNR`, and we print out all the original data + averages:

```
Score      1      24      HG      1     1.5
Score      2      26      HG      2     1.5
Score      5      56      RP      0.5   0.75
Score      7      82      RP      1     0.75
Score      12     97      GM      5     5
Score      32     104     LS      3     3
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! The file twice at the end isn't something I have seen before.

Comment: It just means `awk` gets the same file twice. Like saying `file1`, `file2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1 pass through the file, but you have to store in memory the entire file, so disk i/o vs memory tradeoff:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} 
    {total[$4] += $5; n[$4]++; line[NR] = $0; key[NR] = $4} 
    END {for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print line[i], total[key[i]] / n[key[i]]}
' file
```